# React JS - warnings while running the npm add gh-pages command

Tags: reactjs, npm

I am trying to add gh-pages to my project but failed to succeed , getting the below warnings.

[please find the below image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfZ65.png)

Answer (score 0):

Looking carefully at the error, you can notice there are two dependencies requiring to have babel and typescript listed on your dependencies in order to work.

You should then be able to fix your problem by simply running:
`npm i --save-dev @babel/core^7.13.0 typescript`

Comment: I tried to run the above cmd in master folder but its giving me an below error
JoshAvin@JOSHAVIN1 MINGW64 ~/desktop/coding/reactbasics/monsters-rolodex/monsters-rolodex (main)
$ npm i --save-dev @babel/core^7.13.0 typescript
npm ERR! code ENOLOCAL
npm ERR! Could not install from "@babel\core^7.13.0" as it does not contain a package.json file.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\JoshAvin\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-06-22T17_38_00_396Z-debug.log